# How to match words and an empy string

Tags: regex, null

Newbie of regex here! :D

I have to match the string "SOMETHING HERE" in this example:

DATA[SOMETHING HERE]

SOMETHINGHERE can be NULL (﻿DATA[]) and I have to match it too.
SOMETHINGHERE can anything, carriage returns and line breaks included

Comment: What have you tried so far?  Post some code so we can see that you have at least attempted your problem, then we can guide you on where you went wrong.

Comment: @Kelix I tried \[DATA\[(.+)]] but it doesn't match the NULL characters, cr and lb.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might be looking for `DATA\[(.*)\]`, where
`\[` escapes `[` character, `.` is any character and `.*` means here can be zero or more any characters.

**EDIT**

I didn't was able to test it and I was sure it will work until I noticed [this](http://www.regular-expressions.info/dot.html):

> The dot matches a single character, without caring what that character is. The only exception are line break characters. In all regex flavors discussed in this tutorial, the dot does not match line breaks by default.
>
> This exception exists mostly because of historic reasons. The first tools that used regular expressions were line-based. They would read a file line by line, and apply the regular expression separately to each line. The effect is that with these tools, the string could never contain line breaks, so the dot could never match them.

So `.` match *almost* all characters (excluding CR and LF). So you can use this:

```
DATA\[([^a]*[a]*)*\]
```

It's exactly: *match character, which's not 'a' or 'a'* (you can use any character here)